# Google Colab yolov3 darknet stops at loading weights from "insert darknet directory" Done! Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.0005

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo

I follow the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTCmL3S4Obw&t=4s to a tee yet it does

**loading weights from /content/drive/MyDrive/yolo_custom_model_Training/custom_weight/darknet53.conv.74...Done!
Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.00**
then stops
the whole result is

```
yolov3_custom
layer     filters    size              input                output
    0 conv     32  3 x 3 / 1   608 x 608 x   3   ->   608 x 608 x  32  0.639 BFLOPs
    1 conv     64  3 x 3 / 2   608 x 608 x  32   ->   304 x 304 x  64  3.407 BFLOPs
    2 conv     32  1 x 1 / 1   304 x 304 x  64   ->   304 x 304 x  32  0.379 BFLOPs
    3 conv     64  3 x 3 / 1   304 x 304 x  32   ->   304 x 304 x  64  3.407 BFLOPs
    4 res    1                 304 x 304 x  64   ->   304 x 304 x  64
    5 conv    128  3 x 3 / 2   304 x 304 x  64   ->   152 x 152 x 128  3.407 BFLOPs
    6 conv     64  1 x 1 / 1   152 x 152 x 128   ->   152 x 152 x  64  0.379 BFLOPs
    7 conv    128  3 x 3 / 1   152 x 152 x  64   ->   152 x 152 x 128  3.407 BFLOPs
    8 res    5                 152 x 152 x 128   ->   152 x 152 x 128
    9 conv     64  1 x 1 / 1   152 x 152 x 128   ->   152 x 152 x  64  0.379 BFLOPs
   10 conv    128  3 x 3 / 1   152 x 152 x  64   ->   152 x 152 x 128  3.407 BFLOPs
   11 res    8                 152 x 152 x 128   ->   152 x 152 x 128
   12 conv    256  3 x 3 / 2   152 x 152 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   13 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   14 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   15 res   12                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   16 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   17 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   18 res   15                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   19 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   20 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   21 res   18                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   22 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   23 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   24 res   21                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   25 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   26 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   27 res   24                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   28 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   29 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   30 res   27                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   31 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   32 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   33 res   30                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   34 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
   35 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
   36 res   33                  76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 256
   37 conv    512  3 x 3 / 2    76 x  76 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   38 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   39 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   40 res   37                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   41 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   42 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   43 res   40                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   44 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   45 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   46 res   43                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   47 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   48 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   49 res   46                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   50 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   51 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   52 res   49                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   53 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   54 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   55 res   52                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   56 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   57 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   58 res   55                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   59 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   60 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   61 res   58                  38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 512
   62 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 2    38 x  38 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   63 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   64 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   65 res   62                  19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x1024
   66 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   67 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   68 res   65                  19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x1024
   69 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   70 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   71 res   68                  19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x1024
   72 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   73 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   74 res   71                  19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x1024
   75 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   76 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   77 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   78 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   79 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 512  0.379 BFLOPs
   80 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x1024  3.407 BFLOPs
   81 conv     24  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x  24  0.018 BFLOPs
   82 yolo
   83 route  79
   84 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x 512   ->    19 x  19 x 256  0.095 BFLOPs
   85 upsample            2x    19 x  19 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 256
   86 route  85 61
   87 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 768   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.568 BFLOPs
   88 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   89 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   90 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   91 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x 256  0.379 BFLOPs
   92 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 512  3.407 BFLOPs
   93 conv     24  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 512   ->    38 x  38 x  24  0.035 BFLOPs
   94 yolo
   95 route  91
   96 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 128  0.095 BFLOPs
   97 upsample            2x    38 x  38 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 128
   98 route  97 36
   99 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 384   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.568 BFLOPs
  100 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
  101 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
  102 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
  103 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128  0.379 BFLOPs
  104 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256  3.407 BFLOPs
  105 conv     24  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x  24  0.071 BFLOPs
  106 yolo
```

This confuses me a lot as in the video yolo trained for him and it didn't give this error yet in my case it did.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have installed darknet from here: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

I had the same problem exactly because i had installed darknet from another repository.